# vb.NET Tutorial: String to charArray to String gives unexpected result. Bug?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I am following online tutorials re-learning Visual Basic as incarnated in Visual Studio 2015. The tutorials are very boring, but I'm going through them anyway in case a gem or two might be hiding in them. In one tutorial, we create a String, convert it to a CharArray, reverse the array, then print it out to the console one character at a time. All good. Then I decided to just convert the array back to a String and use WriteLine, for kicks...

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim myText As String = "Hey, this is a string!"
    Console.WriteLine(myText)

    Dim myCharArray() As Char = myText.ToCharArray()
    Array.Reverse(myCharArray)

    Dim reversedText As String = myCharArray.ToString()
    Console.WriteLine(reversedText)

    ' Console output is:

    ' Hey, this is a string!
    ' System.char[]

    ' Even less intuitive, for me, this:
    Console.WriteLine(myCharArray)
    ' produces this:

    ' !gnirts a si siht ,yeH

    ' in the console. While this:
    Console.WriteLine(myCharArray.ToString())
    ' gives System.char[] again.

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

Obviously, WriteLine has no issue with writing out an array of characters. My question is why it prints the String conversion of a character array as System.char[], even when that conversion is explicitly assigned to an object of type String, when it has no problem printing other String objects as their actual string representation.

I realize this is a trivial and stupid thing to ask about, but if there is an underlying cause that knowledge of will help me avoid a bug or two, I would like to know it.

Comment: To convert char array to string, you should pass it as parameter to string constructor.

Comment: That makes sense. I only used to .toString() method of CharArray because it came up in intellisense as one of the methods available to tinker with. I assume by your response that .toString() doesn't actually convert it to a String? While .toCharArray does convert a String to a CharArray?

Comment: Infact, `ToString` converts the `Char[]` to a string, string representation of type name. But you need to convert it to the string created from characters in the array.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov cleared it up for me in an answer below. Good note to file away for the future. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myCharArray.ToString()` calls `Array.ToString()` that uses default implementation of `Object.ToString` which simply returns type name.

You want to construct string from character array instead - [String(Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dim reversedText As New String(myCharArray)
```

Comment: Thank you. That is the piece of the puzzle I was missing. The other answers/comments gave the correct implementation. The why is what I wasn't getting.

Answer (score 1):

To convert char array to string, you should pass it as parameter to string constructor.

```
Dim str = "This is a string!"
Console.WriteLine(str) ' This is a string!
Console.WriteLine(str.ToCharArray().ToString()) ' System.Char[]
Console.WriteLine(New String(str.ToCharArray())) ' This is a string!
```

Infact, `ToString` converts the `Char[]` to a `String`; but string representation of type name, while you need to convert `Char[]` to a string created from characters in the array.